# Intel compiler undefined reference to symbol 'for_inquire'

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, intel, intel-fortran

I'm running a Makefile given to me to compile some Fortran code along with some C++ code. This is being compiled on CentOS using the intel compiler.I didn't write any of the code or the Makefile, also I have no clue what I'm doing.

When I run the Makefile script I get the following error when trying to do something with Fortran code 'libStuff':

```
ld: /home/myProject/trunk/libStuff/lib/libStuff.a(stuff.o): undefined reference to symbol 'for_inquire'
/opt/intel2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcore.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
make[1]: *** [myProject] Error 1
```

I've played around with the Makefile and I've figured out that I need to add a flag to a specific line

```
MYFORTRANCODE=-L$(MYFORTRANCODE_LIB) -lSTUFF -lmpi_usempif08 -lmpi_mpifh  -l_I_NEED_TO_ADD_SOMETHING_HERE
```

The problem is I don't know which flag to add, and couldn't find any helpful documentation on the intel website. Also I couldn't figure out what the 'for_inquire' thing means.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: That said, @ajh1111 we are certainly missing the important info here, like the relevant part of the Makefile, more of the output and the actual command that generated the error message. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @VladimirF: You're far more experienced in Fortran than I am. I'll defer to your judgement and remove my close vote. No problem. :-) I've cleaned up my comments as well, so they don't mislead anyone else. The poster still needs to provide the MCVE with the makefile and command line.

Comment: The requested symbol is part of the Fortran compiler's run time.  As others have said, you'll need to tell us more about how you are compiling/linking for us to tell you how to point the linker to that run time.  If you are using ifort to link then that's a very different problem from if you are using g++ (or ld directly) to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flag I needed to add was -lifcore. I figured it out.

Comment: This answer is not very useful for others without appending the requested details. Therefore I have voted to close the question. We do not even know which command do you use.

Comment: Associating 'for_inquire' error with the compiler switch -lifcore seems pretty useful in itself.

Comment: -lifcore is, as the name suggests, the "core" run-time library for Intel Fortran. This is where all of the Fortran language support stuff, including I/O, is. It's usually recommended to use "ifort" to link applications with Fortran code and let it supply the right libraries. There are others that might be needed (ifport, for example).